# How to remove disabled Google account from Macbook?

Tags: macos, icloud, google-chrome, google

I had a work Google account. When I left my job, the account was disabled, but whenever I try to use my Google account for accessing something, it asks me to choose between my personal account, and this disabled account (which doesn't work, because it's disabled). I want to remove this account completely, so it doesn't keep suggesting I use it.

Both iPhone and Mac use iCloud so they could be sharing account setup information. my iPhone does not see the disabled account, but my MacBook still does.

How do I remove it from my MacBook so that I no longer have to choose between my current Google account and my old disabled account?

Comment: Where are you asked to choose? In a browser, in Mail, in System Preferences, somewhere else? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Any website that asks if you want to use Google account to sign up (instead of making a username/password), e.g. https://www.flowdock.com/signup, https://www.khanacademy.org/signup/google

Answer (score 1):

One simple means would be to make a new user account on the Mac.

You can verify the undesired account isn't in the systems preferences and then start using the google services you wish.

If the accounts are still tied together, you know it's coming from google and the servers in the "cloud" and not your settings.

If everything is good on the new account, then start going app by app and removing saved passwords, saved accounts, cookies and session caches until you clear up all the automation you have accumulated for the old and now undesired account.

App by app might start with: Safari, Keychain, Chrome, System Preferences (accounts)